# Why does JavaScript event refreshes page

Tags: javascript, regex

So i have this code to do a search using RegExp , it goes through an array of strings and searches the user input :

```
Clinica.prototype.pesquisarDoente = function ()
{
    var exp = document.getElementById("pesquisaInput").value;
    var lista = document.getElementById("listaDoentes");
    if (exp)
    {
        while (lista.firstChild)
        lista.removeChild(lista.firstChild);
        var patt = new RegExp(exp);
        var lenght = this.doentes.length
        for ( i = 0; i < lenght; i++)
        {
            if (patt.test(this.doentes[i].nome))
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.doentes[i].toString()));

                lista.appendChild(option);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

and then i call this in an event:

```
var buttonPesquisa = document.createElement("input");
    buttonPesquisa.type = "submit";
    buttonPesquisa.value = "Pesquisar";
    buttonPesquisa.addEventListener('click', function () { cl.pesquisarDoente(this); });
```

wich i then append to my page. the problem is, when i click the button, it clears the select list and then refreshes the page. why is that ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are creating a submit button which once clicked will trigger a submit event which will appear to be refreshing the page...

You need to `preventDefault()` on the event.

Try this:

```
var buttonPesquisa = document.createElement("input");
    buttonPesquisa.type = "submit";
    buttonPesquisa.value = "Pesquisar";
    buttonPesquisa.addEventListener('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); cl.pesquisarDoente(this); });
```

Comment: it worked ! it doesnt find anything but i guess i have the regexp wrong. It doesnt refresh now :)

Comment: This works but IMHO it's better to not use a submit button if you don't want to submit form data in the conventional way. Use a normal button instead.

Comment: yeah i changed it now but still needed the prevent default

Answer (score 2):

Submit buttons submit forms.

Submitting a form will send the form data to the URI specified by the action (or the current URI if there is no action) and load the response as a new page.

Comment: i changed to: var buttonPesquisa = document.createElement("button");
 buttonPesquisa.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Pesquisar"));
 buttonPesquisa.addEventListener('click', function () { cl.pesquisarDoente(this); });

Comment: A `<button>` element is, by default `type="submit"` so that wouldn't change anything.

Comment: oh i see ! thats why i still needed to prevent default

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of the button to 'button':

```
var buttonPesquisa = document.createElement("input");
    buttonPesquisa.type = "button";
    buttonPesquisa.value = "Pesquisar";
    buttonPesquisa.addEventListener('click', function () { cl.pesquisarDoente(this); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var buttonPesquisa = document.createElement("button");
buttonPesquisa.type = "button";
// rest of code
```

And it shouldn't refresh your page.